# Table with multirow, colors and raggedright

Tags: tables, alignment

I'm already 3 days trying to create simple table as I have in Word.
I want to create some template for me.
I tried many converters to LaTeX, but it doesn't answer on all my requirements.
That what I get m but have to fix several things.
I almost sure I don't need multicolumn in the code. Just to set alignment for some row.

[image: Table]

1. I draw the lines (`\hhline`) with cell color where I did `\multirow`, but still there is some line there, depending on zoom. Also in PDF Foxit reader. I tried to use `\hline` and `\cline` but they don't work properly with colored cells. Is there option to change the line width?
2. I use `\multirow` and the text inside the cell is not in the middle if I use `\multicolumn` also. If I remove `\multicolumn` it comes to the middle. BUT I defined it in the top by `>{\raggedright}p{0.2\textwidth}|`. So I want to place it or in the top inside the cell OR option to drop it a little down from the top line, a little bit more control on the placing inside the cells.
   Also I wanted to do alignment left-top, or left-middle, but without to set width of the cell, is it posible?

3-4. If I have one long sentence, I expect it should be moved to another line automatically according to the size of the column. But if I need to join cells by `\multirow` it doesn't work if the sentence inside the `\multirow` and I must to use `tabular`. If I don't need to join cells, I can take out a sentence from `\multirow` and it will brake the sentence to several lines as expected.
In the code line 43 outside `\multirow`, goes to a next line automatically.
In the line 46 inside `\multirow` because I need to use `\multirow` to join several cells, and I must to use `tabular`. It doesn't goes to other line automatically.

5. Some cells I want to do alignment center-middle, but without set column width. How I do that?

```
% Automatically added code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
% End of automatically added code


\begin{table}[H]
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%

\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}p{0.2\textwidth}|>{\raggedright}p{0.2\textwidth}|c|c|c|c|>{\raggedright}p{0.3\textwidth}|}
%{|l|l|c|c|c|c|l|}%>{\raggedright}p{0.12\textwidth}

\hhline{-------}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{79, 129, 189}Parameter}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{79, 129, 189} Details}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{79, 129, 189} Min}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{79, 129, 189} Typ}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{79, 129, 189} Max}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{79, 129, 189} Unit}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{79, 129, 189} Notes}}\tabularnewline
\hhline{|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|}


\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{ 79, 129, 189}VDD}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{184, 204, 228}VDD2\_b\_a}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{184, 204, 228} 1.71}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{184, 204, 228} 2}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{184, 204, 228} 2.2}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{184, 204, 228} {[}V{]}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{184, 204, 228}2V ±5\%}} \tabularnewline
\hhline{|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|}

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{ 79, 129, 189}}}  &
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{219, 229, 241}VDD1V8\_c\_d}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{219, 229, 241} 0.9}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{219, 229, 241} 1.}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{219, 229, 241} 1.2}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{219, 229, 241} {[}V{]}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{219, 229, 241}}}  \tabularnewline
\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor[RGB]{79, 129, 189}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-|-|-|-|-|}

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{ 79, 129, 189}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{219, 229, 241} }} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{219, 229, 241} 1.0}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{219, 229, 241} 1.2}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{219, 229, 241} 1.29}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{219, 229, 241} {[}V{]}}} &
\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{219, 229, 241}}1.20V ±10\%, on save mode also work 5{[}V{]} input  \tabularnewline
\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor[RGB]{79, 129, 189}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor[RGB]{219, 229, 241}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-|-|-|-|-|}

\multirow{-3}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{ 79, 129, 189}\begin{tabular}[l]{@{}l@{}}Open Source \\SDevice\end{tabular}}  &
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{219, 229, 241}VDD5V2\_sssss\_ttttt}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{219, 229, 241} 0.95}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{219, 229, 241} 1.0}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{219, 229, 241} 1.05}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{219, 229, 241} {[}V{]}}} &
\multirow{1}{*}{\cellcolor[RGB]{219, 229, 241}}1.00V ±20\%, on save also work 3{[}V{]}   \tabularnewline
\hhline{|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|}


\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

% Automatically added code
\end{document}
% End of automatically added code
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should complete your code example so that it can be compiled as is; it seems to be missing some packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do that tabular with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. You won't see thin whites lines, whatever PDF viewer you use.

However, you need several compilations.

```
\documentclass[x11names,svgnames,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{p{25mm}lccccX[l,m]}[hvlines]
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor[RGB]{79,129,189}{1}
  \columncolor[RGB]{79,129,189}{1}
  \rectanglecolor[RGB]{184,204,228}{2-2}{2-*}
  \rectanglecolor[RGB]{219,229,241}{3-2}{5-*}
\Body
  Parameter & Details & Min & Typ & Max & Unit & Notes \\ 
  VDD & VDD2\_b\_a & 1.71 & 2 & 2.2 & [V] & 2V ±5\% \\
  \Block{3-1}{Open Source Device  }
  & VDD1V8\_c\_d & 0.9 & 1. & 1.2 & [V] & \\
  & \Block{2-1}{VDD5V2\_sssss\_ttttt}  & 1.0 & 1.2 & 1.29 & [V] & 1.20V ±10\%, on save mode also work 5[V] input \\
  &  & 0.95 & 1.0 & 1.05  & [V] & 1.00V ±20\%, on save also work 3[V] \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Why it doesn't work ?

! Fatal Package nicematrix Error: Bad column type.(nicematrix) The column type '\CodeBefore ' in your(nicematrix) environment {NiceTabularX} is unknown.(nicematrix) This error is fatal.Type <return> to continue.... \rowcolor

Comment: Strange... Is your TeX installation up to date?

Comment: My Texmaker ver 5.1.3
MikTeX console 4.9 instaletion file 22.10x64

Comment: You should try to update with the button `Updates` in MikTeX console.

Comment: I updated everything.
I think I found , it conflicts with 
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}

Comment: Ah... When `tabularx` is loaded, you should write `\begin{NiceTabularX}{\linewidth}`... and `\end{NiceTabularX}`.

Comment: Ok, I found that I don't use these packages , so I deleted it , also "colortbl".
Now I see , that I need to RUN 2-3 times to get the table , what can I do to avoid it ? And what is LaTeX editor which gives a quick compilation ? I write code and compile 20 000 time every day ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144934/discussion-between-f-pantigny-and-ikif).

Answer (score 3):

For such a table, I would suggest that you use the `tabularray` package. It gives all possible controls. The documentation is fantastic and huge.

I have recast your table for `tabularray` and changed the separator horizontal rules to white. Most of the members on this forum would strongly suggest you to avoid vertical lines in a table. The only problem I faced is I could not get rid of the thin vertical white space between the columns.

```
%
\documentclass[x11names,svgnames,11pt]{article}
%
\usepackage[body={15cm,23cm},centering]{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tabularray}
  \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx} 

\begin{document}

\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\begin{tblr}{
  width=1\textwidth, stretch=1.5,
  cell{1}{1-7} = {bg=azure3, fg=white},
  cell{1-5}{1} = {bg=azure3, fg=white},
  cell{2}{2-7} = {bg=azure7},
  cell{3}{2-7} = {bg=azure8},
  cell{4-5}{2-7} = {bg=azure9},
  colspec  = {llSSSlX[l, 3cm]}
  }
\toprule
  Parameter & Details & Min & Typ & Max & Unit & Notes \\ 
\hline[white]
  VDD & VDD2\_b\_a & 1.71 & 2 & 2.2 & [V] & 2V ±5\% \\
\hline[white]
\SetCell[r=3]{m, 2cm} Open Source Device  
  & VDD1V8\_c\_d & 0.9 & 1. & 1.2 & [V] & \\
\cline[white]{3-7}
  & \SetCell[r=2]{m, 3.5cm} VDD5V2\_sssss\_ttttt  & 1.0 & 1.2 & 1.29 & [V] & 1.20V ±10\%, on save mode also work 5[V] input \\
  \cline[white]{3-7}
  &  & 0.95 & 1.0 & 1.05  & [V] & 1.00V ±20\%, on save also work 3[V] \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: THank you.
What is a problem with vertical lines ?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution using of `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[body={15cm,23cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkB}{RGB}{ 79, 129, 189}     % dark blue
\definecolor{mediumB}{RGB}{184, 204, 228}   % dark blue
\definecolor{lightB}{RGB}{219, 229, 241}    % dark blue

\usepackage{tabularray}         % version 2023A
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\newlength\colwidth

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\settowidth\colwidth{Parameter}
\noindent
\begin{tblr}{row{1} = {guard, bg=darkB,fg=white},
             row{2} = {bg=mediumB},
             row{3} = {bg=lightB},
            colspec = {Q[l, wd=4.4em, bg=darkB,fg=white] l
                       SSS
                       c X[l, m]},
            hlines, vlines, 
              }
Parameter   & Details & Min & Typ & Max & Unit & Notes \\
VDD         & VDD2\_b\_a & 1.71 & 2 & 2.2 & [V] & 2V ±5\% \\
\SetCell[r=3]{l}    Open Source Device
    & VDD1V8\_c\_d  & 0.9 & 1.      & 1.2 & [V] & \\
    & \SetCell[r=2]{l} VDD5V2\_sssss\_ttttt  
        & 1.0       & 1.2 & 1.29    & [V] & 1.20V ±\qty{10}{\%}, 
                                      on save mode also work \qty{5}{\volt} input \\
    &    & 0.95     & 1.0 & 1.05    & [V] & 1.00V ±\qty{20}{\%},   
                                      on save also work \qty{3}{\volt} \\
\end{tblr}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]